# Concurrent transitioning paths in separate SVG elements

Tags: javascript, d3.js, svg

I am trying to make four separate real-time graphs to be displayed in their own svg elements (not sure if this or what I wrote is good practice), and managed to make all the x-axes continuously transition. However, when I add in the paths, they and the axes jump and do not smoothly transition. Could anyone help me with simultaneously transitioning the paths with the axes? Any insight would be appreciated, as I'm pretty new with D3. Thank you so much!

```
var n = 45,
      duration = 1000;

var properties = {
    "#count": {
        data: d3.range(n).map(function() { return 1000; })
    },
    "#relativeHumidity": {
        data: d3.range(n).map(function() { return 2000; })
    },
    "#temperature": {
        data: d3.range(n).map(function() { return 3000; })
    },
    "#pressure": {
        data: d3.range(n).map(function() { return 4000; })
    }
};

// margin convention
var margin = {top: 35, right: 70, bottom: 35, left: 70},
    width = 960 - margin.left - margin.right, // 900
    height = 500 - margin.top - margin.bottom; // 494

var now = Date.now(),
    offLeft = now - (n - 3) * duration,
    firstPoint = offLeft + duration,
    lastPoint = firstPoint + (n - 4) * duration;

// chop off last two for basis interpolation
var x = d3.time.scale()
    .domain([firstPoint, lastPoint])
    .range([0, width]);

var y = d3.scale.linear()
    .domain([0, 10000])
    .range([height, 0]);

var line = d3.svg.line()
    .interpolate("basis")
    .x(function(d, i) { 
      return x(now - (n - 3) * duration + i * duration); 
    })
    .y(function(d, i) { return y(d); });

for (prop in properties) {

    var item = properties[prop];

    item.svg = d3.select(prop).append("p").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // mask 
    item.svg.append("clipPath")
        .attr("id", prop + "clip")
        .append("rect")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height);

    item.xAxis = item.svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "x axis")
        .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
        .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

    item.svg.append("text")
        .attr("x", width)
        .attr("y", height + margin.bottom)
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Time");

    item.svg.append("text")
        .attr("transform", "rotate(-90)")
        .attr("y", 0 - 55)
        .attr("x", 0)
        .style("text-anchor", "end")
        .text("Count")

    item.yAxis = item.svg.append("g")
        .attr("class", "y axis")
        .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(y).orient("left"));

    item.path = item.svg.append("g")
        .attr("clip-path", "url(#" + prop + "clip)")
        .append("path")
        .datum(item.data)
        .attr("class", "line")
        .attr("d", line);    
}

function tick() { 
    // update endpoints 
    now = Date.now(),
    offLeft = now - (n - 3) * duration,
    firstPoint = offLeft + duration,
    lastPoint = firstPoint + (n - 4) * duration;

    // add value
    for (prop in properties) {
        var item = properties[prop];
        item.data.push(Math.random() * 300 + 5000);
    }

    // update domain
    x.domain([firstPoint, lastPoint]);

    // slide the x-axis left
    d3.selectAll(".x.axis")
         .transition()
         .duration(duration)
         .ease("linear")
         .call(d3.svg.axis().scale(x).orient("bottom"));

    var count = 0;
    // slide the line left
    d3.selectAll("path")
         .attr("d", line)
         .attr("transform", null)
         .transition()
         .duration(duration)
         .ease("linear")
         .attr("transform", "translate(" + x(offLeft) + ",0)")
         .each("end", function() {
        count += 1;
        if (count === 4) {
            count = 0;
            tick();
        } 
    }); // FIXED!

    for (prop in properties) {
        var item = properties[prop];
        item.data.shift();
    }
}

tick();
```

EDIT: Fixed! But I don't think it's pretty. What was causing the jump was each transition calling the tick function over and over after it finished (since they don't all finish at the same time), causing it to be called at least 4x more than normal (creating a jump). All I did was add an index that would only recursively call the tick function every time it hit 4. Added it in.

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: I've tried to but it won't display anything. Will keep on trying and add if it works.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/3Rk5N/500/